# Complex decisions based on at least two parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm interested in clean code and I don't think this reads very well:

```
if ((var1 === 'A' && !(var2 === 'B')) || var1 === 'B' || var1 === 'D' || var2 === 'A')
```

If it was only one variable (var1) I could make an object literal as a value map, but with two variables together I find it hard to make this cleaner, any suggestion?

Comment: there is a parentheses too much. where belongs the opening part to?

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't overthink thinks like this too much. Best options for a long if statement is just to put them on multiple lines to increase readability:

```
if (
  (var1 === 'A' && var2 !== 'B') ||
  var1 === 'B' ||
  var1 === 'D' ||
  var2 === 'A'
)
```

You also could put the first expression in a separate variable to make it even more readably, though it all comes down to personal preference.

```
const isANotB = var1 === 'A' && var2 !== 'B';

if (
  isANotB ||
  var1 === 'B' ||
  var1 === 'D' ||
  var2 === 'A'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array and push the conditions to it. Then using `.some()` check for `true`.

```js
var1 = "A";
var2 = "A";


let check = [];
check.push(var1 === 'A' && (var2 !== 'B'));
check.push(var1 === 'B');
check.push(var1 === 'D');
check.push(var2 === 'A');

/*
or 
check = [var1 === 'A' && (var2 !== 'B'), var1 === 'B', var1 === 'D', var2 === 'A'];
*/
console.log(check.some((currentValue) => currentValue == true));
```